# Landscape mode for lecture notes

Tags: landscape

I am trying to make notes for a talk I have to deliver, in LaTeX.

I want to make it look like http://gunion.physics.ucdavis.edu/gunion/renormalization.pdf.

What package do I require to make notes like these?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Unfortunately I can't open the link, but the general advice would be to simply ask the author of the presentation, any other opinion is just going to be a guess.

Comment: Hello @AndrewSwann. Thanks for your reply. I'll do that, but an educated guess would work just as well. By the way, the link works for me.